# How to replace .sheet with another one?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view

```swift
struct Services: View {
  @State private var isFirstSheetOpen = false
  @State private var isSecondSheetOpen = false

  var body: some View {
     Button("Open sheet") {
       isFirstSheetOpen.toggle() // turns true
     }.sheet(isPresented: $isFirstSheetOpen) {
        Button("Open second sheet") {
          isFirstSheetOpen.toggle() // turns false
          isFirstSecondOpen.toggle() // turns true
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isSecondSheetOpen) {
          Text("Second sheet")
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I want to achieve something like Telegram has.

When opening the second sheet the first one should close (with animation).

https://s4.gifyu.com/images/IMG_8720.gif

I have two problems with my code.

1. If I put sheets nested (like in the example above) it closes the first one, then again opens it, even before opening the second sheet.
2. If I put sheets like this

```swift
// cut
   Button() {
   }.shet() { /*...*/ }
    .shet() { /*...*/ }
// cut
```

It replaces the sheets immediately. If I wrap it inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
  isSecondSheetOpen = true
}
```

animation takes too long (event with a small delay).

Could you help me to achieve exactly the same animation as shown in Gif?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sheet(item:)` instead of `isPresented`, which will close a previous sheet and open a new one when the `item` changes:

```
struct SheetContent: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var content: [SheetContent] = [.init(text: "1"), .init(text: "2"), .init(text: "3")]
    @State var presented: SheetContent?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Open") {
            presented = content.first
        }
        .sheet(item: $presented) { item in
            Text(item.text)
            Button("New sheet") {
                presented = content.filter { $0.id != presented?.id }.randomElement()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... It seems like this approach is working only for different sheets with the same shape of data (and the same design). What if I need to have two absolutely different views? P.S. It is possible to customize the animation speed of the closed window? It seems like your approach has a small delay between opening closing and opening new sheet.

Comment: I don't know of any way to customize the speed. In regards to the first part of your question, no, this approach doesn't rely on the same design or shape of data at all -- you just need some way for `item` to represent what you want to render and then render based on that. It could be an `enum` with associated values, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Combine to trigger a second boolean after whatever interval.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFirstSheet = false
    @Published var willShowSecondSheet = false
    @Published var showSecondSheet = false

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $willShowSecondSheet
            .dropFirst()
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] newValue in
                // Perform the desired action after the debounce interval
                self?.showSecondSheet.toggle()
            }
    }
}


struct BottomDrawerView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show First Sheet") {
                viewModel.showFirstSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showFirstSheet) {
            VStack {
                Text("First Sheet")
                    .padding()
                Button("Show Second Sheet") {
                    viewModel.showFirstSheet.toggle()
                    viewModel.willShowSecondSheet.toggle()
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showSecondSheet) {
            Text("Second Sheet")
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
        
    }
}

struct BottomDrawerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BottomDrawerView()
    }
}
```